# From ODE Hill kinetics to stochastic mass action

Tags: simulation, bioinformatics, rate, deterministic, stochastic-process

I am facing a problem translating a model with ODE to a stochastic model.

The original model contains two expressions:

1) k6f2*PKB_S473P^n6/(km6^n6+PKB_S473P^n6))*AS160

2) k9f1*S6K*mTORC1a^n9/(km9^n9+mTORC1a^n9)

that are described with Hill kinetics.

I was wondering how to tranlate the previous two expressions into a mass action law, to be able to simulate them with a stochastic simulator.

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transforming Hill kinetics into mass action kinetics cannot be done in a satisfying way, because for large concentrations, the former lead to *bounded* rates, while the latter does not. Mass action law will not show the saturation effect that can be seen with Hill kinetics. At best, you can approximate the Hill function *locally* with mass action, but then your simulation should be done around a stable steady state. Alternatively, if you introduce intermediate species and reactions with appropriate coefficients, you can obtain Michaelis-Mentens kinetics (Hill kinetics with unit Hill coefficient). In principle, you could even regain cooperativity using more complex intermediate species, but this is probably rather involved.

Comment: Thank you!

What do you mean with "you can approximate the Hill function locally with mass action"?

Must I write the Hill function as it is, or must do some changings? ... and, what do you mean with "locally"?

Comment: Well, if you look close enough at a regular function, it looks like a straight line. Here, if you zoom at a particular portion of your Hill function, you can find a polynomial function (mass action kinetics) which is very close to it. But further from this portion, the approximation will get worse. This is what i meant by locally: you cannot find a new mass action kinetics expression that will correctly approximate the hill function for any concentration.